# Pandas sequence string match on rows and get the best match rows ids

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Suppose that we have the following pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
data_dic = {
    "values": ['jk4', '293','814' ,'er b3', '1', " sas", '<', '37', '/',3, '5651 + sdfv 84083', '+', '814 gfj67 340f', "sas " ,'293', '<', 'df gfdh', ' .', ':9271', '1', '3-', '=', '5', '293', "sas "],
    "rowNr": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
}
data = pd.DataFrame(data_dic)
```

given a specific string how can we get the rows IDs that match best? for example let say that the input string was: `" sas 293 <"` then the output IDs would be `[13,14,15]` which corresponds with the best match in this dataframe.

Example 2: for the input string `"814 gfj67 340f "` the output would be `[12]`

Example 3: for the input string `". :92711"` the output would be `[17,18,19]`

Comment: In a conceptual level, what is your criteria to compare strings?

Comment: the output row-nums must be consecutive, and match the input when concatenated?

Comment: When concatenated the output needs to match the input given a specific %, for example 90%

Comment: this % is for char by char comparison?

Comment: yes % for char by char comparison

Comment: the algorithm must find the highest match sequence, i will calculate the % after i get the IDs and create the logic to deal with that afterwards. But i need the IDs for other reasons as well, not just the concatenated string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, here goes my try.

I calc the strongest match just by counting matching chars,
I go on all possible concatenations, and pick the best one based on that score.

```py
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

data_dic = {
    "values": ['jk4', '293', '814', 'er b3', '1', " sas", '<', '37', '/', 3, '5651 + sdfv 84083', '+', '814 gfj67 340f',
               "sas ", '293', '<', 'df gfdh', ' .', ':9271', '1', '3-', '=', '5', '293', "sas "],
    "rowNr": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
}
data = pd.DataFrame(data_dic)
data['values'] = data['values'].astype(str)

all_index_pairs = [(j, i) for i in range(len(data)) for j in range(i)]
all_concats = [''.join(data.loc[[*range(*pair)]]['values'].values) for pair in all_index_pairs]


def calc_match(s1, s2):
    return sum(1 for x, y in zip(s1.replace(' ', ''), s2.replace(' ', '')) if x == y)


def get_best_match(s):
    best_pair = max(zip(all_index_pairs, all_concats), key=lambda x: calc_match(s, x[1]))[0]
    return [*range(*best_pair)]


in1 = " sas 293 <"
in2 = "814 gfj67 340f "
in3 = ". :92711"

print(get_best_match(in1))
print(get_best_match(in2))
print(get_best_match(in3))
```

Output:

```
[13, 14, 15]
[12]
[17, 18, 19]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here You go:

=^..^=

```
import pandas as pd
data_dic = {
    "values": ['jk4', '293','814' ,'er b3', '1', " sas", '<', '37', '/',3, '5651 + sdfv 84083', '+', '814 gfj67 340f', "sas " ,'293', '<', 'df gfdh', ' .', ':9271', '1', '3-', '=', '5', '293', "sas "],
    "rowNr": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dic)


input_string = "sas 293"
split_string = input_string.split(' ')

for item in split_string:
    find_match = df['values'].str.match(item).fillna(False)
    index = df.index[find_match].tolist()
    print(index)
```

Output:

```
[13, 24]
[1, 14, 23]
```